# How do I put data into 3rd column?

Tags: layout, customize

I'm using the Fishpig plugin for Wordpress integration, and I have the layout set to 3columns-left.
I have a sidebar on the left, and posts in middle, but I can't figure out how to put things on the right, because there doesn't seem to be a container over there to reference.

How can I add images (or any kind of data) to the column on the right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the 3columns layout, then you need to specify that in page xml file like this one.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         
    </body>
</page>
```

For more information how to add data on specific location, you can read this one.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html

Comment: I set the page to 3columns, but I can't figure out how to get data into the 3rd column